# Constant invariant quantities

Tags: probability-theory, mathematical-physics, finance, economics

What is the intuition behid the constant invariant quantities and why do we need it? How is this related with probability theory?

I was solving some maximization problem and when I saw the answer, the author mendtioned that since the quantity $\mathbf{B}\in L^2(\Omega,\mathbb{F},\mathbb{P})$ is constant invariant then it holds that $\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{B})=0$ and she only considers - uses the variance of the r.v. to find the maximum.

Comment: Please ask a more specific question. Add all relevant information about the subject you ask and what you already know about it.

Comment: Well, in fact I know nothing, the only thing that I have ever seen in my life was during an excercise that I was solving for some maximization problem. When I saw the answer, the author mendtioned that since the quantity $\mathbf{B}\in L^2(\Omega,\mathbb{F},\mathbb{P})$ is constant invariant then it holds that $\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{B})=0$ and she only considers - uses the variance of the r.v. to find the maximum.

Comment: Include your additional information to your question so that any user can see it at the first glance. For this purpose use the edit function.

Comment: Well, I can not write the whole problem. Unless, you mean my answer to you as addintional information

Comment: Yes, I mean what you have written in the comment. If you then have the feeling that you should add other additional information go ahead.